# Как сделать так, чтобы при регистрации пользователя, создавался поддомен?

Tags: php

Допустим у меня есть пользовательская регистрационая форма на сайте, я хочу чтобы, при регистрации аккаунта, аккаунт привязывался к своему поддомену, на котором он уже бы и работал как сервис и пользователь выполнял все нужные ему действия. Как реализовать такую систему? Я использую стек PHP+JS ну и на хостинге есть cPanel.

Идея такова, чтобы структура: `domain.com/users/username1` нужно преобразовать в `username1.domain.com`

Спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Создавать поддомен при регистрации пользователя не нужно.
Это работает не так.

Надо [DNS](http://Wildcard%20DNS%20record) основного домена один раз настроить так, чтобы все субдомены указывали на тот же самый сервер.

После этого в скрипте получить субдомен из HTTP_HOST и выдать соответствующую страницу.

.htaccess тут не при чем.

Comment: А есть возможность, получить более развёрнутый ответ, включая примеры реализации?

Comment: @ummahusla, конкретизируйте вопрос, обозначьте, что именно и насколько глубоко вдаваясь вам нужно объяснить.

Answer (score -1):

По поводу автоподдоменов можно прочитать на данном [ресурсе](http://webdev.wakh.ru/2013-02-13/subdomanins-htaccess), физически они будут как подпапки на главном домене, но работать будут как поддомены. Также как описал это товарищ **Shorty**, придется перенаправить поддомены на главный домен.

Comment: Ставим минусы.... а в любом ведь случае придется выставлять единую точку входа, через .htaccess (если все делается по MVC)

Comment: здесь не принято отвечать ссылками. Ссылка может умереть, и тогда будет не очень приятно.